# Ignoring version validation on PHPmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Grettings everyone, is it possible to ignore PHPmyAdmin validation for the minimum version of MySQL?

Here is the issue for me. The server where it is installed, is running on the latest version, but, one of the servers I have to admin is running on 5.0. And since the verificiation was fixed, I can't upgrade PMA or I can't access that server anymore.

Comment: Sure it should be possible … go lock at the source code, find out where they do that validation – and remove it. The more important question: Would you _want_ that? Using it on a less then required database version might have unexpected results. I’d suggest you rather update pma, and then set up a second “old” version separately, and configure to be only able to access that one old database server. (Plus sensible additional access control – because it is an outdated script.)

Comment: I was hoping for a config option, so I wouldn't have to change the source code every time there is an update. The thing about using it on an older version is that a lot of options won't work, but for what I use that won't be a problem. I will check the source then, thanks